# validacion de un formulario mediante ajax y jquery-validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

Buenas tengo el siguiente problema, he realizado una función para poder actualizar mis datos con PHP y Codeigniter, utilizando AJAX también.. todo funciona bien, pero resulta que quiero validar mi formulario usando jquery-validate antes de realizar la petición AJAX, para eso ya tengo mis reglas de validación y mi código es el siguiente:

```html
function editar(id = null) 
{
  if(id) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'roles/get_datos_id/'+id,
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      success:function(response){

        $("#edit_nombre").val(response.Nombre);
        $("#edit_descripcion").val(response.Descripcion);      

        $("#form_edit").unbind('submit').bind('submit', function() {
         
          var form = $(this); 
          
            $.ajax({
              url: form.attr('action') + '/' + id,
              type: 'post',
              data: form.serialize(),
              dataType: 'json',
              success:function(response) {
                if(response.success === true) {
                    $("#modal_editar").modal('hide');
                    alert('se actualizaron los datos');
                    $("#form_edit")[0].reset();
                    tabla_datos.ajax.reload(null, false);  
                  }else{
                    $("#modal_editar").modal('hide');
                    alert('error al actualizar los datos');
              }// /succes
            }); // /ajax
           return false;  
        });       
      }
    });
  }
  else {
    alert('error');
  }
}
```

El código funciona bien.. actualiza mis datos.. ahora mi duda es donde agregar el siguiente código con mis reglas de validación:

```html
$('#form_editar').validate({

            highlight: function (input) {
                $(input).parents('.form-line').addClass('error');
            },
            unhighlight: function (input) {
                $(input).parents('.form-line').removeClass('error');
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                $(element).parents('.form-group').append(error);
            }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

agregalo en tu

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
});
```

y luego agrega esto en tu validate

```
$( "#form_editar" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#form_editar').validate({

        highlight: function (input) {
            $(input).parents('.form-line').addClass('error');
        },
        unhighlight: function (input) {
            $(input).parents('.form-line').removeClass('error');
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            $(element).parents('.form-group').append(error);
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
          form.submit();
        }
  });
});
```

Comment: hola, gracias por responder. la parte del submitHandler.. la coloco dentro de mi funcion editar? que parte cambiaria en ese  lugar

Comment: Colocala dentro de tu validate, edito el código para mayor claridad

Comment: muy bien y mi funcion editar, queda tal cual? no cambiaria nada?

Comment: si la tienes en tu action de tu form entonces no cambiaría ni se pondría en ningún otro lugar, pruebalo y a ver que tal

Comment: lo probe, si puedo actualizar los datos, pero no me valida nada :(

Comment: intenta metiendolo dentro del submit del form de la siguiente forma

Comment: lo probare, mi peticion ajax qedaria dentro del submitHandler?